# How to copy the contents of a set to a two dimensional array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, set

The idea is to have a two dimensional array NxN where all the elements (numbers from 0 to N*N) are in random positions. To generate the random numbers I used:

```
 // Creates a set so we avoid repetition of generated numbers
        Set<Integer> generatedNumbers = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
        while (generatedNumbers.size() < numberOfElements){
            Integer next = rng.nextInt(numberOfElements) ;
            generatedNumbers.add(next);
        }
```

Now I need to copy the elements to a two dimensional array. Basically, something like this:

```
   for (Integer number: generatedNumbers){
            // Here I'd like to have: 
           // 1st iteration: board[0][0] = number
          // 2nd iteration: board[0][1] = number
          // ...
          // last iteration: board[3][3] = number
        }
```

where:

```
board = new int[boardSize][boardSize];
```

with boardSize = 4 for this particular case.
Btw, if there's a better way to achieve the same but using a different method, I'd be happy to read it.

Comment: Do you know how to fill a 2D array with all 1s for example?

Comment: yes I do. I'd just do for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++)
                                 for (int j = 0; j < array.length();j++)
                                        array[i][j] = 1;

Comment: Replace that 1 with your random generated numbers.

Comment: In the future I would suggest waiting more then 20 minutes before accepting an answer so you can see all your options before choosing, as I believe my answer gives you an actual code implementation along with comments. This also give a bit of time for those answering to better formulate their answers instead of racing against the clock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to randomly distribute numbers from a collection into a 2d array. Here is a working code based on what you gave us that will do just that:

```
public static Integer[][] getRandomNumbersArray(int base) 
{
    Random rng = new Random();
    int numberOfElements = base * base;

    // Let's use a list so we access by index
    List<Integer> generatedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) 
    {
        // Generate our random number
        Integer next = rng.nextInt(numberOfElements) ;

        // Check if the number is already added
        if (!generatedNumbers.contains(next)) {
            generatedNumbers.add(next);
        }
        // Number was a duplicate, redo loop cycle
        else i--;
    }
    // Create our board array here
    Integer[][] array = new Integer[base][base];

    // Index used to access the list
    int i1 = 0;

    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < base; i2++) 
    {
        // Populate board row
        for (int i3 = 0; i3 < base; i3++, i1++) {
            array[i2][i3] = generatedNumbers.get(i1);
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Integer[][] array = getRandomNumbersArray(4);

    System.out.println("Here is how our board looks like:");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Here is how our board looks like:
[8, 7, 11, 3]
[15, 5, 1, 0]
[2, 9, 10, 12]
[13, 4, 6, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating the set on the outside of the loop, consider doing it in reverse. Something along the lines of

```
Iterator iter = generatedNumbers.iterator()
for (...) {
     for (...) {
          if (iter.hasNext()) arr[i][j] = iter.next()
          else ...
     }
}
```

Comment: should I change how generatedNumbers is defined? (Set<Integer> generatedNumbers = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(); ) because when I try to do what you said I get an error: Required: int, Found: java.lang.object

Comment: Fixed. A casting was enough: (int) iter.next(). Not sure why I needed it tho, but now my problem is solved.